# How to re-install ubuntu that is pre-installed by manufacturer

Tags: 12.04, canonical, preinstallation

Actually I wiped off ubuntu 12.04 lts that was pre-installed by manufacturer and want to just have it back is there any of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to do a fresh install of Ubuntu. For example, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

Comment: I have already installed ubuntu by this method but pre-installed ubuntu was a little bit different and it has "Restore system to factory state" and "Recovery" options in grub menu

I want to know from where I can download that ubuntu